# Element 'APIKey': This element is not expected - Rally and Jira connector version 4.7.2

Tags: rally

I'm running the Rally and Jira Integration tool version 4.7.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 and keep on getting this error:

> ERROR : Class.initialize - The configuration file is not valid - the errors were:
>    Element 'APIKey': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( WorkspaceName, Projects, User, Password, ArtifactType, ExternalIDField, SuppressDeprecationWarning, CrosslinkUrlField, CopySelectors, UpdateSelectors ).

On version 4.6.5 the same configuration files ran successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also getting the same error. Here is how I resolved it:

1. Update your config.xml file to include the following tags with the username and password in cleartext:

   ```
   <User>username</User> 
   <Password>password</Password>
   ```
2. Execute the connector e.g. 
       ca_agile_central2_jira_connector.rb config.xml -1
3. Open config.xml, you will see the username and password encrypted e.g.

   ```
   <User>SECURED-HASH</User> 
   <Password>SECURED-HASH</Password>
   ```
4. The secure hashes can now be used continuously on the machine where it was generated. When you change workstations, re-generate the hash, otherwise you will get the following error:

   > ERROR : Class.initialize - EnvironmentalKey ident_vector not valid for
   >   decryption target value